# disable add new row in sessions table in laravel

Tags: laravel, session

I have laravel 5.0 . and set sessions drivers to database . I have some link that no require to insert new row in sessions table . how i can disable inserting new row only for `www.site.com/download` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this solution is good for laravel 5.0 
first must define two middleware in `app/http/kernel.php` .first middleware is lesssession . lesssession is for route that do not need session .and second is hasssession middleware .hassession is good for route that need session :

```
<?php namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel {

    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * @var array
     */

    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate',
        'hassession' => [
            'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode',
            'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies',
            'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse',
            'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession',
            'Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession',
            'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',
        ],
        'lesssession' => [] ,
        'auth.basic' => 'Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth',
        'guest' => 'App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated',
    ];

}
```

step 2:
put route in two group by edit `app/http/route.php`:

```
<?php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['lesssession']], function()
{
    Route::get('download', function(){
        // do some stuff for download file
    });
});
Route::group(['middleware' => ['hassession']], function()
{
    // all other route that need session 
});

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new route/middleware type for sessionless access. Do this by adding a new middleware group in your Http/Kernel that doesn't include the `StartSession` middleware, then adding a new route file to hold all your download links, and then registering your new route file in your `RouteServiceProvider`.

Edit the `$middlewareGroups` array in `app/Http/Kernel.php` to look like the following:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],

    'sessionless' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

];
```

Then edit your `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider` to map your newly-created route file:

```
Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'sessionless',
    'namespace' => $this->namespace,
    'prefix' => 'download',
], function ($router) {
    require base_path('routes/downloads.php');
});
```

Now add a file in your `/routes` directory named `downloads.php`, and add your downloadable routes there. If you want to use a wildcard to parse what file they're looking for, you can, or you can explicitly list what routes will trigger a download:

```
Route::get('test', function(){
    $file = '/path/to/test/file';
    return response()->download($file);
});

Route::get('{fileName}', function($fileName){
    $file = '/path/to/' . $fileName;
    return response()->download($file);
});
```

This doesn't address using headless authorization, which you would need if you didn't want unauthorized access to all of your `sessionless` routes.

Comment: Agree, your answer is more flexible and correct, your way you can sessionless multiple routes, Thank you.

Comment: this is for laravel 5.0 or laravel 5.3 ?

Comment: The structure would work for either, but you'd probably want to put the downloads routes file in `app/Http/routes` instead of `routes/`

Comment: thank you.your answer give a good idea and a good point for start resolve my problem.but actually that not work perfectly.